# JS Regex: Replace all but first

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I make a Regex which replaces all occurrences of a word but the first?
I have a webpage with loads of text and a header at the top. I want to make a regex which replaces all occurrences of a word but the first because I don't want the header to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var count = 0;
text = text.replace(myRegex, function(match) {
    count++;
    if(count==1) {
        return match;
    }
    else {
        return myReplacedValue;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
var i = 0;
"foo foo foo".replace(/foo/g, function(captured/*, offset, originalString */) {
    if ( i++ ) {
        return 'bar';
    }
    return captured;
});
```

Comment: what does `if(i++)` do?

Comment: it increments `i` each cycle. so, the first time it is 0, which is falsy. So, it skips the first match, but afterwards will be truthy.

Answer (score 1):

great answer abstract... i have never seen replace used like that before

heres a nice cluttered version..

```
text = text.replace(/boo/g, function(match) {return (++count==1)?match:myReplacedValue});
```

Comment: Thanks. Replace function has `(regex, callback)` style for arguments, just search it a bit. :)